# Fetching current category in magento

Tags: magento, categories

Im trying to get the current category from *catalog/product/view.phtml*

```
<?php 
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$item = $this->getProduct();
$curCat = Mage::registry('current_category');

if($curCat && $curCat->getId() == Mage::helper('function')->NEWS_CAT_ID) {
        // do stuff
}
?>
```

The major problem with this method is; Im getting the parrent category_ID(2) instead of the child category_ID(10). How do i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SinisterGlitch, you was goes to this page from catalog search page....registry have save it current category default category ,whose ids is 2.That means the product call from category is save as current category

Answer (score 0):

check your root category form admin panel you probably add this product to root category also.